# Next <a> tag in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that look like that :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a id="firstTAG" class="jp-play-me" data="foo"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a id="secondTAG" class="jp-play-me" data="bar"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a id="thirdTAG" class="jp-play-me" data="foobar"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And a javascript/jQuery function :

```
function getnextmedia(current) {
    var res = current.split("/");
    rowId = "#" + res[5];

    $(".jp-play-me").each(function() {
        if (this.id == rowId) {
            alert(this.data);
            alert($(this).next(".jp-play-me").attr("data"));
        }
    });
}
```

`rowid` is an `id` Im looking for in the table. I use the class `jp-play-me` to find all `<a>` tags and then compare `id` to get the good `<a>` tag. That works fine.

The next step is to get the following `<a>` tag in the table so the function can read the `data` attribute.

For exemple, if `rowId` is equal to `secondTAG` then I need to get the value `foobar`, which is the value of the following `data` `<a>` tag attribute.

I tried to use the `next()` method but I guess I do it the wrong way.

Let me know if you need more informations.

Comment: On what event is this function called, and what is `current`, a node, an attribute-value, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the `.next()` method returns the **immediately following sibling** element. Since the anchor elements are not siblings, nothing is returned.

In order to get the anchor element in the next `tr` element, you would need to select the closest `tr`, *then* find the anchor element in the next `tr`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('.jp-play-me').attr("data");
```

```
$(".jp-play-me").each(function() {
    if (this.id == rowId) {
        // Next <a>
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.jp-play-me').attr("data");
    }
});
```

References:

- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Great !! Exactly what i need !! Gonna read some documentation about closest(), next(), find() methods ! Ty again.